# WCF method call returning web service disco page

Tags: wcf, discovery

I have a WCF web service and application that works fine in developemnt.  I've published the WCF on an IIS Server and am able to use it from the web app inside the firewall addressing it by server name.  HOWEVER, now that I've put it out for use externally, it is causing problems.

My web app is getting an error trying to connect.  I can see the service, disco, wsdl, etc from inside and outside the firewall, but when I make my first call for authentication from the outside, the service is returning the DISCO page instead of processing the authentication method call.  This results in a ProtocolException because as I understand it, the app is expecting xml, not html.

Again, exact same web app works fine interally hitting the IIS server.
One difference being externally I'm getting to it from a web address, internally i'm using the server name.  But the service loads in a web browser outside the firewall using the web address.

Partial web app config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding 
      name="WSHttpBinding_IWebService" 
      closeTimeout="00:03:00"
      openTimeout="00:03:00" 
      receiveTimeout="00:10:00" 
      sendTimeout="00:03:00"
      bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
      transactionFlow="false" 
      hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
      maxBufferPoolSize="5000000" 
      maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000" 
      useDefaultWebProxy="true" 
      allowCookies="false">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5000000" 
        maxArrayLength="5000000"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
        enabled="false" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <transport 
          clientCredentialType="Windows" 
          proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message 
          clientCredentialType="Windows" 
          negotiateServiceCredential="true"
          algorithmSuite="Default" 
          establishSecurityContext="true" 
          />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://<dns address/server address>/WebService.svc"
    binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IWebService"
    contract="WebServiceRef.IWebService" name="WSHttpBinding_IWebService">
    <identity>
      <dns value="localhost" />
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
  <endpoint
    address="mex"
    binding="mexHttpBinding"
    contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</client>
```

Partial service web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>

    <bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding 
      name="ServiceBinding" 
      openTimeout="00:03:00" 
      sendTimeout="00:03:00"
      transactionFlow="false" 
      maxBufferPoolSize="5000000" 
      maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000">
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<services>
  <service 
    behaviorConfiguration="xxx.WebServiceBehavior"
    name="xxx.WebService">
    <endpoint 
      address="http://<dns address/server address>/WebService.svc"
      binding="wsHttpBinding" 
      bindingConfiguration="ServiceBinding"
      contract="xxx.IWebService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint 
      address="mex" 
      binding="mexHttpBinding" 
      contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
    <behaviors>
```

/WebService.svc"/>